# Laravel & PEST Php | Github Actions | cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 8000

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, github-actions, laravel-7

I would like to run Github Actions on a Laravel Project with PEST PHP but I'm receiving errors when running the HTTP Facade to hit a local API within my testsuite.

```
cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

I've tried to change the APP_URL on the Github .env but without any success. On my local machine test working as expected.

- http://localhost
- http://localhost:80
- http://localhost:8000
- http://127.0.0.1:800
- http://127.0.0.1:80

**Code that gets hit via the test**

```
   $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ])->post(route('create.country'), [
            'name_de' => $name_de,
            'name_fr' => $name_fr,
            'name_it' => $name_it,
            'name_rm' => $name_rm,
            'iso_alpha_2' => $iso_alpha_2,
            'iso_alpha_3' => $iso_alpha_3,
        ]);
```

**Github Actions**

```
name: "PEST"

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:

  laravel-tests:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:latest
        env:
          MYSQL_USER: github_actions
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: github_secret
          MYSQL_DATABASE: github_actions
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: github_secret
        ports:
          - 3306
        options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 1
      - name: Prepare the environment
        run: cp .env.github .env
      - name: Set Composer config
        run: composer config disable-tls true
      - name: Install Composer dependencies
        run: composer install --no-progress --no-suggest --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
      - name: Generate key
        run: php artisan key:generate
      - name: Execute PEST
        env:
          DB_PORT: ${{ job.services.mysql.ports['3306'] }}
        run: ./vendor/bin/pest --coverage
```

**Github .env**

```
APP_NAME="Application"
APP_ENV=testing
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
```

Comment: I'm also battling with this now and my what a pity you didn't get an answer. So far my conclusion is that the remote VPS installed by GitHub doesn't have an HTTP server running. In my case that's fine because I'm mocking but apparently even if you mock cURL tries to find a server.